# Mongodb: How can I add a field to each of the documents in an array whose value is calculated from two other fields in each of the documents?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e4c1d75ee4aacf2d13847d"),
    "ventas" : [
        {
            "producto" : "A",
            "precio" : 52,
            "cantidad": 5
        },
        {
            "producto" : "B",
            "precio" : 10,
            "cantidad": 4
        },
        {
            "producto" : "C",
            "precio" : 15,
            "cantidad": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add a new field "ingreso" to each document in the "Ventas" array whose value will be the product of price and quantity, like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e4c1d75ee4aacf2d13847d"),
    "ventas" : [
        {
            "producto" : "A",
            "precio" : 52,
            "cantidad": 5,
            "ingreso": 260
        },
        {
            "producto" : "B",
            "precio" : 10,
            "cantidad": 4,
            "ingreso": 40
        },
        {
            "producto" : "C",
            "precio" : 15,
            "cantidad": 6,
            "ingreso": 90
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage of MongoDB aggregation and operators such as [$multiply](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

Here is the example of the similar pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "ventas": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$ventas",
          "as": "v",
          "in": {
            "cantidad": "$$v.cantidad",
            "precio": "$$v.precio",
            "producto": "$$v.producto",
            "ingreso": {
              "$multiply": [
                "$$v.precio",
                "$$v.cantidad"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
])
```

See it in action here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kYmNuntf4lh